# 30 people vote for 5 proposals

Tags: probability, combinatorics

$30$ people are voting for $5$ proposals. If each person only votes for $1$ proposal, in how many ways can the votes be distributed?

My attempt: Since every person only votes for $1$ proposal, it's like throwing $30$ names into $5$ distinct boxes which from basic counting is $\dbinom{30+5-1}{5-1} = \dbinom{34}{4}$ but the answer in the book is $6$ times larger.

Is the book wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: It should be $5^{30}$ because people are different. If you are just considering the number of people, then you are correct

Comment: $6 \cdot  \dbinom{34}{4}= \dbinom{34}{5}$. Probably a mistake, unless there is a sixth box for people who don't vote.